# Count specific value in label expression by QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression

I have successfully count total features of Parcel layer by count aggregate function, next challenge with me is how to count all "5" or "4" values from "lut_zone" field as a label expression.

[image: here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this task you need to add a filter to the aggregate function, you can combine it with IN operator to add several values to the filterlist:

```
aggregate(@layer_name,'count',"lut_zone","lut_zone" IN (4,5))
```

This will give you the amount of features having a 4 or 5 as integer value in lut_zone. You can extent the IN list as you like.